# Como limitar os click de um botão?

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou fazendo o sistema de configurações do MacBook da apple onde dependendo das configurações o preço aumenta na hora.
Mas estou com um problema onde se eu clicar mais vezes na config desejada ele continua adicionando os preço. E eu quero limitar para quando eu clicar nele 1 vez ele bloqueia ou não responde mais o click se eu tentar clica de novo.

*Vou ter que usar JSFiddle para vocês testar o codigo por conta da parte do código CSS que é muito grande*

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ryaufsn/)

(Lá em baixo fica o total que é atualizado na hora) 
(OBS: Eu ja procurei algo relacionado mas não me ajudou)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>13-inch MacBookPro - @CauaS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mac.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="NavUp">
        <ul>
            <li>aa</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <header class="McP"> <!-- Specs-->
        <h3>MacBook Pro</h3>
        <p>Overview</p>
        <p>macOS</p>
        <p>Tech Specs</p>
        <hr>
    </header>

    <section class="trade">  <!--Trade ----->
        <h4>Add a trade-in</h4>
        <p>Get a refund of up to $2530 when you trade in an eligible computer, or recycle it for free.*</p>
        <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        <hr>
    </section>

    <div class="Info">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <h1>Customize your 13-inch <br>
        MacBook Pro - Space Gray</h1>
        <section class="specs">
            <p>1.4GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation Intel Core i5 processor, Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz <br>
            </p>
            <p>8GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 memory</p>
            <p>128GB SSD storage</p>
            <p>Retina display with True Tone</p>
            <p>Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 </p>
            <p>Two Thunderbolt 3 ports</p>
            <p>Backlit Keyboard - US English</p>
            <hr>
        </section>
        <section class="ModificProcessor"> <!-- COnfig Process-->
            <h6>Processor</h6>
            <a href="#" class="Better">What processor is right for you ?</a>
                <div class="Hz14"> <!-- config 1.4Hz-->
                    <p><strong> 1.4GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation <br>
                        Intel Core i5 processor, <br>
                        Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz</strong></p>
                </div>

                <div class="Hz17"> <!-- config 1.7Hz-->
                    <p><strong>1.7GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation <br>
                        Intel Core i7 processor, <br> 
                        Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz
                       </strong> + $300.00</p>
                </div>
        </section>

        <section class="ModificMemory"> <!-- config Memory-->
            <h6>Memory</h6>
            <a href="" class="BetterMemory">How much memory  is right for you? 
 </a>
                <div class="GB8"><br> <strong> 8GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 
 Memory</strong></div>
                <div class="GB16"><br><strong> 16GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 Memory 
  </strong>+ $200.00 </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <nav class="NavDown"> <!-- Barra parte de baixo-->
        <hr>
        <p class="Pick">Pickup:</p>
        <a href="#" class="Check">Check availability</a>
        <div class="imgShop"></div>

        <p class="Deli">Delivery:</p>
        <p class="Stock">In Stock <br>
            Free Shopping</p>
        <a href="" class="Get">Get delivery dates</a>
        <div class="imgBox"></div>

        <h1 class="price">$</h1>
    </nav>


    <script src="Mac.js"></script>
</body>
```

**jAVASCRIPT**

```
var Price = document.querySelector('.price');
//Processor
var Config1 = document.querySelector('.Hz14'); //1.4Hz , quad-core ,i5 
var Config2 = document.querySelector('.Hz17'); //1.7Hz, quad-core, i7

//Memory
var Memory8 = document.querySelector('.GB8'); //8GB
var Memory16 = document.querySelector('.GB16'); //16GB

 NormalPrice = 1.299;

 Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice;
 /*Porcessor*/
 Config2.onmouseenter = function() {
 Config2.style.borderColor = '#888888';

 }
 Config2.onmouseout = function() {
 Config2.style.borderColor = '#cfcfcf';
 } 

 Config2.onclick = function() {
    Config1.style.border = '0.5px solid #cfcfcf';
    Config2.style.border = '1.5px solid #0070c9';
    NormalPrice = NormalPrice + 0.300;
    Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice ;


    Config2.onmouseout = function() {
        Config2.style.borderColor = '#0070c9';
    } 
 } 

   //Memory
   Memory16.onmouseenter = function() {
   Memory16.style.borderColor = '#888888';

 }
   Memory16.onmouseout = function() {
   Memory16.style.borderColor = '#cfcfcf';
   } 

   Memory16.onclick = function() {
   Memory8.style.border = '0.5px solid #cfcfcf';
   Memory16.style.border = '1.5px solid #0070c9';
   NormalPrice = NormalPrice + 0.200;
   Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice; 

    Memory16.onmouseout = function() {
        Memory16.style.borderColor = '#0070c9';
    }
 }
```

*Desculpe a organização do codigo*

*Codigo css ta no JSFiddle, por causa do tamanho*

Comment: Por favor, coloque o seu código no POST, evite de colocar apenas no JSFiddle

Comment: Você precisa de algo desse tipo: https://www.javatips.net/api/ant-master/rxlibrary/src/main/java/support/ui/adapters/debounced/DebouncedClickHandler.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja apenas impedir que o valor aumente uma possível implementação pode ser:

```js
var Price = document.querySelector('.price');
//Processor
var Config1 = document.querySelector('.Hz14'); //1.4Hz , quad-core ,i5 
var Config2 = document.querySelector('.Hz17'); //1.7Hz, quad-core, i7
var hasClickProcessor =  true;
var hasClickMemory =  true;

//Memory
var Memory8 = document.querySelector('.GB8'); //8GB
var Memory16 = document.querySelector('.GB16'); //16GB

NormalPrice = 1.299;

Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice;
/*Porcessor*/
Config2.onmouseenter = function() {
    Config2.style.borderColor = '#888888';
        
}
Config2.onmouseout = function() {
    Config2.style.borderColor = '#cfcfcf';
} 

Config2.onclick = function() {
  if(hasClickProcessor){
      Config1.style.border = '0.5px solid #cfcfcf';
      Config2.style.border = '1.5px solid #0070c9';
      NormalPrice = NormalPrice + 0.300;
      Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice ;


      Config2.onmouseout = function() {
          Config2.style.borderColor = '#0070c9';
      }
    }
    hasClickProcessor = false;
     
} 

//Memory
Memory16.onmouseenter = function() {
    Memory16.style.borderColor = '#888888';
        
}
Memory16.onmouseout = function() {
    Memory16.style.borderColor = '#cfcfcf';
} 

Memory16.onclick = function() {
  if(hasClickMemory){
      Memory8.style.border = '0.5px solid #cfcfcf';
      Memory16.style.border = '1.5px solid #0070c9';
      NormalPrice = NormalPrice + 0.200;
      Price.innerHTML = NormalPrice; 

          Memory16.onmouseout = function() {
              Memory16.style.borderColor = '#0070c9';
          }
    }
    hasClickMemory = false;
   
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.NavUp {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

/* Specs ---------------------*/
.McP {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.McP h3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 12px;
}

.McP p {
    display: inline-block; /*Um do lado do outro */
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 900px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: gray;
    top: -12px;
}

.McP hr {
    color: #cfcfcf;
    border: 0.5px solid;
}

/* Trade -----------*/
.trade {
    width: 100%;
    
}

.trade h4 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

.trade p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.trade a {
    position: relative;
    left: 640px;
    top: 20px;
    color: #0086d8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.trade hr {
    color: #cfcfcf;
    border: 0.5px solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}

.Info .img {
    background-image: url(Pro.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 380px;
    height: 330px;
    position: relative;
    left: 210px;
    top: 50px;
}

.Info h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 690px;
    top: -270px;
}

.Info .specs {
    position: relative;
    left: 690px;
    top: -250px;
}

.Info .specs p {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.Info .specs hr {
    width: 550px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    border: 0.5px solid;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

/*Processor ----------*/

.Info .ModificProcessor {
    position: relative;
    left: 690px; 
    top: -195px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Info .ModificProcessor h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Info .ModificProcessor .Better {
    color: #0086d8;  
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.Info .ModificProcessor .Hz14 {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #0070c9;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.Info .ModificProcessor .Hz17 {
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: #cfcfcf;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


/*Memory --------------- */
.Info .ModificMemory {
    position: relative;
    left: 670px; 
    top: -195px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
}

.Info .ModificMemory h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Info .ModificMemory .BetterMemory {
    color: #0086d8;  
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.Info .ModificMemory .GB8 {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #0070c9;
    width: 550px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Info .ModificMemory .GB16 {
    border: 0.5px solid;
    border-color: #cfcfcf;
    width: 550px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}









/* Nav Down -----------------*/
.NavDown {
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}
.NavDown hr {
    width: 100%;
    color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.308);
    border: 0.5px solid;
} 

.NavDown .Pick {
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 30px;
}

.NavDown .Check {
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 30px;
    color: #0086d8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.NavDown .imgShop {
    background-image: url(ShopL.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 22px;
    height: 29px;
    position: relative;
    left: 170px;
    top: -7px;
}

.NavDown .Deli {
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    top: -35px;
}

.NavDown .Stock {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    font-size: 13px;
    top: -30px;
    color: gray;
}

.NavDown .Get {
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    font-size: 13px;
    top: -32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0086d8;
}

.NavDown .imgBox {
    background-image: url(BoxL.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    left: 370px;
    top: -105px;
}

.NavDown .price {
    position: relative;
    left: 900px;
    top: -130px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>13-inch MacBookPro - @CauaS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mac.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="NavUp">
            <ul>
                <li>aa</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header class="McP"> <!-- Specs-->
            <h3>MacBook Pro</h3>
            <p>Overview</p>
            <p>macOS</p>
            <p>Tech Specs</p>
            <hr>
        </header>

        <section class="trade">  <!--Trade ----->
            <h4>Add a trade-in</h4>
            <p>Get a refund of up to $2530 when you trade in an eligible computer, or recycle it for free.*</p>
            <a href="#">Get Started</a>
            <hr>
        </section>

        <div class="Info">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <h1>Customize your 13-inch <br>
            MacBook Pro - Space Gray</h1>
            <section class="specs">
                <p>1.4GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation Intel Core i5 processor, Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz <br>
                </p>
                <p>8GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 memory</p>
                <p>128GB SSD storage</p>
                <p>Retina display with True Tone</p>
                <p>Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 </p>
                <p>Two Thunderbolt 3 ports</p>
                <p>Backlit Keyboard - US English</p>
                <hr>
            </section>
            <section class="ModificProcessor"> <!-- COnfig Process-->
                <h6>Processor</h6>
                <a href="#" class="Better">What processor is right for you ?</a>
                    <div class="Hz14"> <!-- config 1.4Hz-->
                        <p><strong> 1.4GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation <br>
                            Intel Core i5 processor, <br>
                            Turbo Boost up to 3.9GHz</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Hz17"> <!-- config 1.7Hz-->
                        <p><strong>1.7GHz quad‑core 8th‑generation <br>
                            Intel Core i7 processor, <br> 
                            Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz
                           </strong> + $300.00</p>
                    </div>
            </section>

            <section class="ModificMemory"> <!-- config Memory-->
                <h6>Memory</h6>
                <a href="" class="BetterMemory">How much memory  is right for you?</a>
                    <div class="GB8"><br> <strong> 8GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 Memory</strong></div>
                    <div class="GB16"><br><strong> 16GB 2133MHz LPDDR3 Memory </strong>+ $200.00 </div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <nav class="NavDown"> <!-- Barra parte de baixo-->
            <hr>
            <p class="Pick">Pickup:</p>
            <a href="#" class="Check">Check availability</a>
            <div class="imgShop"></div>

            <p class="Deli">Delivery:</p>
            <p class="Stock">In Stock <br>
                Free Shopping</p>
            <a href="" class="Get">Get delivery dates</a>
            <div class="imgBox"></div>

            <h1 class="price">$</h1>
        </nav>


        <script src="Mac.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```